# Developing an application that spreads across multiple monitors

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, multiple-monitors

I apologize if this is not the proper forum for this question - but I'm looking to develop an application that will spread itself across multiple monitors (not the same image duplicated on multiple monitors, but 1 image filling the 4 monitors). I'd prefer to write it in as3 / php / javascript, but will consider something like C# if necessary. Does anyone have any tips for getting started on this? The platform can be PC or MAC, but it'd be nice to have some out of the box software that would facilitate the projection of the software onto the multiple monitors.

Comment: If you need to detect dual monitor then javascript won't be able to do that (however you can make the user select that with resolution and open 2 window into each monitor). It can open multiple window, talk between each window it opened and well does what it does. AS3 might have more tools to allow such things as it often have more control than JS

Comment: Unless you're going for multiple windows (something like Eclipse the Adobe applications where you can drag windows across your desktop), AS3 might not be an ideal solution as the stage has a limit of 16MP with a maximum width of 8191 pixels (which would limit the height to 2048 pixels).

Comment: The limitations are helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General answer, hopefully this is helpful.

You can use AIR to deploy an application with multiple windows across different monitors. By using more than one window you would not be limited by the 8191px width cap. IMO this is a better approach than one large window stretching across multiple displays.

Using the [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html) class you access information about the monitors currently available on the system. This class allows you to get an array of the currently available screens `Screen.screens`as well as the screen bounds `screen.bounds`

There is even a wrapper class that makes this process a bit easier:

http://www.joristimmerman.be/wordpress/2009/03/03/screenmanager-expand-your-air-application/

Using this class it looks to be as easy as

```
ScreenManager.openWindowCenteredOnScreen(new window, screen number);
```

It also looks like it has some other methods that would be useful in your case

```
ScreenManager.stretchWindowToAllScreens() //would be limited by the stage size cap
ScreenManager.openWindowFullScreenOn()
```

You can use `screen.visibleBounds`to get the correct sizing information when creating a new window.

You can then use the [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) to create and open a new application window on another display. This code should help you get started

```
var window:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow();
var content:Sprite = new Sprite(); //a container for some display objects to appear inside your new window
window.stage.addChild(content); //adding the content to the new window;
window.activate();
```

Using this you will be able to create 4 windows, one for each display, and attach a different image to each one. You can also set each of these screens to the full width and height of each display.

Answer (score 1):

I do this successfully using a couple of methods, for fixed setups/installs:

**A single Air app** with a stage size of QFHD (3840x2160 - ie 4 x HD, configured as 2x2). Then in in the application.xml simply set the following, and it will span across them

```
<systemChrome>none</systemChrome>
<transparent>false</transparent>
<visible>true</visible>
<minimizable>false</minimizable>
<maximizable>false</maximizable>
<resizable>false</resizable>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<width>3840</width>
<height>2160</height>
```

**Alternatively** using an ATI eyefinity graphics card you can create one single virtual monitor out of many, and simply use:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

The Eyefinity drivers also give you the ability to compensate for the bezels which is a **great** feature.

Both these methods in my opinion are the best, since they greatly reduce complexity when trying to animate objects across multiple `NativeWindow's`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put this solution out there even though I haven't tested it - it seems there is a purely hardware solution to this - a videowall controller that will take a single video feed and parse it out evenly across four screens. Something like this:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/570090-REG/Smart_AVI_UXST4S_Stretcher_Pro.html

Seems as though it will do the trick without having to figure out anything fancy on the programming side, though obviously it could be cost prohibitive.